# Spring Integration - How to expose as REST service?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to create a Spring Integration WAR application which can be called by external systems as a REST service and my app in-turn makes a multiple web services invocations. How  do i expose my spring integration application as a rest service?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Inbound Gateway with path variable placeholder(s) in the `path` attribute.

See the [rest-http sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/rest-http).